# How to pick a value and reset it from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query `select * from public.transition where from=1 and to= 3 where count>3` which return the below resultset.

```
from   to   count
_____  ___  ______
 1      3     10
```

So this basically when I execute this query I want to reset the count to 9.So whenever another query I query the expected result set should be.

```
from   to   count
_____  ___  ______
 1      3     9
```

Instead of two different queries can I make a single query to reset this.

ANy help is appreciated

Comment: Does your query really execute? Both `from` and `to` are reserved words (according to ANSI SQL), so they need to be delimited, e.g. `"from"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may input an expression using the field itself during update.

```
update
    public.transition
set 
    count = count - 1
where 
    from = 1
    and to = 3
    and count > 3
```